# Save Metabox Custom Field Value

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I am using this code to show post type dropdown to select available post types but when i submit the post it restores the value back to post, how can i make sure it saves it?

```
<select name='my_meta_box_post_type' id='my_meta_box_post_type'>
        <?php $post_types=get_post_types('', 'objects'); foreach ($post_types as $post_type): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($post_type->name); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($post_type->name); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: Where is this select box located? what you are doing to save it's value ? it won't save just by selecting value.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not reinventing the wheel and looking at 
[Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes](https://github.com/tammyhart/Reusable-Custom-WordPress-Meta-Boxes)

Even though this code is no longer supported it's concise enough to be easily manageable.  I use it and it works well.

All you need to do is add the meta_box.php file to your functions.php and from then on use the predefined components:

```
require_once('path_to/metaboxes/meta_box.php');
```

Then use code such as (this is the example from the github page):

```
$prefix = 'sample_';

$fields = array(
    array( // Text Input
    'label' => 'Text Input', // <label>
    'desc'  => 'A description for the field.', // description
    'id'    => $prefix.'text', // field id and name
    'type'  => 'text' // type of field
),
array( // Textarea
    'label' => 'Textarea', // <label>
    'desc'  => 'A description for the field.', // description
    'id'    => $prefix.'textarea', // field id and name
    'type'  => 'textarea' // type of field
)
);

$sample_box = new custom_add_meta_box( 'sample_box', 'Sample Box', $fields, 'post', true );
```

There are also other options such as [CMB2 (Custom Meta Boxes)](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2)
That code appears to have better support but is also much more complex and could be overkill for your needs.